# Resource request questions vs Tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, tag-wiki

I have come across a [discussion](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3427/40657) in the Meta site of WorkPlace about resource/reference request questions.

Are such questions actually on-topic in a site?  I think they are either opinion based and/or too broad.

However, there are always the tag wikis for including the necessary information about relevant resources and references.

Comment: Each site and its own rules. There is no strict rule in Stack Exchange "no opinion based questions" - if the questions are good and the opinions are well formed and focus on the question, it might be accepted on some sites. E.g. from [politics help center page](http://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references"

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Yeah, I understand that for sites like politics, WorldBuilding, etc; it is okay.  But, I think they would be off-topic on sites like CV, SO, etc.  For example, qns like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4993513)

Comment: Exactly, that's why each site got its own set of rules for on topic or off topic questions. We can't really judge or enforce a fixed set of rules.